# Select an element without selecting descendants

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, css-modules

I use CSS Modules which generates random class names for my tags. How can I select an element of specific type without selecting descendants? So far I've tried to use selectors `:first-of-type` and `:first-child` like this:

```
.settings ul:first-of-type > i:first-child {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

But the result is that my rule applies to every `<i>` element on my page.

HTML:

```
<div class="settings">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <i>Select this element</i>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <i>but not this one</i>
                    <span></span>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <i>or not this one</i>
                    <span></span>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Very useful material on 'first-of' selectors in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717480/css-selector-for-first-element-with-class. may or may-not be of interest to OP but useful background on the subject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the CSS child combinator [`>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator):

```css
.settings > ul > li > i {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="settings">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <i>Select this element</i>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <i>but not this one</i>
          <span></span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <i>or not this one</i>
          <span></span>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

> The child combinator (`>`) is placed between two CSS selectors. It
> matches only those elements matched by the second selector that are
> the direct children of elements matched by the first.